# Git command to get list of all committers to files containing specific text

Tags: git, git-log

What git command gets the list of all committers to files containing specific text. This can optionally include a before/after parameter. The problem I am facing is, is there any specific command for this, or can I get the list of files and pipe it to some command?

Comment: Clarifying separately: I want the list of ALL committers to files containing specific text, not just those that added that string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let do that in two stages. 1st let's get the list of files:

```
files=`git grep -l "searh string"`
```

Having the list let's list all commits that touch the files, get the author's name/email for every commit, sort the list of authors printing only unique name/email.

```
git log --format='%an <%ae>' -- $files | sort -u
```

Combine two commands into one:

```
git log --all --format='%an <%ae>' -- `git grep -l "search string"` | sort -u
```

Comment: I want to have the list of people who have committed to these files as well, those who made other changes.

Comment: Ok, I see. Let's do it in 2 stages — 1: get the list of files and 2: get the list of commits that touch the files.

Comment: @phd well done, I've struggled to find it but you were quicker. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

probably something along the lines of

```
git log --all -S "the string you search for" --pretty='%cn%n'
```

---

Details :

`-S` filters commits using the string given in following parameter

`%cn` prints the committer name

`%n` is just a new line

Comment: What I want can be broken down into a two step process. Both I can achieve individually, but not together. 1. Get list of files containing search string 2. Get list of committers into these files. The question is to basically combine these two things.

Comment: @GyanendraSingh Ok this is slightly more complex but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command to git all committers names and emails for files containing specific text:

```
    git log -S "search string" --stat --pretty=format:"%cn -%ce (%cd)"
```

Comment: But I had the impression that OP didn't know the files to search in, only given specific text *in* files.

Comment: If you specify a directory or file
name, you can limit the log output to commits that introduced a change to those files. This is always
the last option and is generally preceded by double dashes (--) to separate the paths from the
options.

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is that OP does *not* know which are the files to filter with, only specific portions of text inside.

Comment: I have added a comment above stating the issue I want to solve, and this is not it.

Comment: @NermeenSaleh this works when you know the "path of files to search in" beforehand. In my case, I don't. Also, I need list of committers to this file as well.

Comment: @GyanendraSingh   in this command " git log -S "search string" --stat --pretty=format:"%cn -%ce (%cd)"  I doesn't specify any paths

Comment: yes, but it does not add the list of people who have made commits in these files.

Comment: %cn -%ce get the names and emails of committers